# Can I have an AppleScript to listen to another application action?

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-elcapitan

So here is what I'm trying to do:

I have an Application that alerts me with a notification sound and the icon bounces when I get a message.

I want to be able to have the Mac to do something else when that happen. Like play another sound or fire up a notification on notification center.

Any way I can get that action from the App (play sound or/and bounce icon) to trigger an Applescript?

Comment: Self created or third-party application?

Comment: third-party application

Comment: Then it's quite impossible unless the target application provides some kind of API.